# Cannot change Canvas.overrideSorting property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

Very odd problem, I have a Canvas object and I am trying to set the overrideSorting flag to true.

```
public void SetSortingLevel(string sortinglayerName)
{
    _canvas.overrideSorting = true;
    _canvas.sortingLayerName = sortinglayerName;
}
```

However, normally this works, however if I put a breakpoint and look at the code, even right after setting the override to true, it is false:

[image]

The api shows this is just a setter/getter. Any idea why this is happening?

I have used this code before and it normally works.

**Note:** This is a nested canvas so it should be allowed to have its sorting layer set.

Answer: As noted in the answer below, the activeInHierarchy check turns out to be false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design. You can only change the value of `Canvas.overrideSorting` on nested canvas.

For example, if you have a `Canvas` which is root of other canvas or UI Objects, you won't be able to change the value of `Canvas.overrideSorting`.

If you have **any** `Canvas` *which is a child* of other `Canvas`, you will be able to change the value of `Canvas.overrideSorting`.

**Requirements for changing `Canvas.overrideSorting`**:

**1**.`Canvas` *which is a child* of other `Canvas`

- Canvas   *//**cannot** change*

  - Canvas  *//can change*

    - Canvas  *//can change*

---

**2**.The GameObject must be active in hierarchy and the `Canvas` component must be enabled in order  to can change `Canvas.overrideSorting`.

Active in hierarchy means that **all** the parent Canvas GameObject of the `Canvas` you want to change its `Canvas.overrideSorting` must be active and the `Canvas` script itself must be enabled. This can be verified with the `gameObject.activeInHierarchy` property.

If `Canvas.gameObject.activeInHierarchy` is **not** `true`, you **cannot** set or change the `Canvas.overrideSorting` property. It is better to check those properties before attempting to change `Canvas.overrideSorting`.

```
if (_canvas.gameObject.activeInHierarchy && _canvas.enabled)
    _canvas.overrideSorting = true;
else
    Debug.Log("Cannot change Canvas overrideSorting");
```

Comment: Yes something I did not make clear in my example, but this is a nested canvas.

Comment: That's fine. Was in the middle of an edit before your comment. See my edit.

Comment: All good points but they checkout fine. I am basically ingratiating some prefabs, adding them to the parent (which has a parent canvas) and trying to set their override. If I go into the inspector and manually set the flags it works, it's just not working in the the code.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you can manually set them in the Editor. What I said in the answer applies to the code you're using. I noticed a ! typo in my answer and also didn't add the enable check. Check if `if (_canvas.gameObject.activeInHierarchy && _canvas.enabled)` is true .  If this is not true, it won't work. I have verified this on my side. Just use `if (_canvas.gameObject.activeInHierarchy && _canvas.enabled)` to verify. Let me know.

Comment: the activeInHierarchy was false.

Comment: @Aggressor Yup. Figured that or _canvas.enabled was the issue. Glad I was able to help

Comment: I feel this is a silent error yes? Perhaps unity should add a flag?

Comment: They just need to update their doc to say what's in my answer.  It doesn't throw error. I think they do some check for these two on the native side before changing that property. Sometimes, there doc i not up to date

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for one frame.

```
private void Start()
{
    Canvas canvas = GetComponent<Canvas>();
    StartCoroutine(OneFrame(() => { canvas.overrideSorting = true; }));
}

private IEnumerator OneFrame(Action callback)
{
    yield return null;
    callback();
}
```